# console.log() truncates on encountering an empty space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a few strings through `console.log()`. The strings are dynamically allocated. For some reason `console.log()` truncates the strings on first encounter of an empty space in the string. Please see the output screenshot below. Please look at the "data-keyword" attribute.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
$.each(data, function(i, jsonObj){
    tempHolder = jsonObj.fields.keyword;
    dataArr[i] = tempHolder;
                                                    
    $('#keywordsDiv').append('<li><label class="form-check-label" style="font-size: 9px; color: red;"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input keywordCheckbox" data-keyword='+tempHolder+' />'+tempHolder+'</label></li>');
});
```

Below is where I try to display the string:

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
            $('#addKeywordsBtn').on('click', function(){
                $.each($('.keywordCheckbox'), function(i, checkboxTag){
                    if(checkboxTag.checked == true){
                        console.log(checkboxTag);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#keywordsDiv').append('<li><label class="form-check-label" style="font-size: 9px; color: red;"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input keywordCheckbox" data-keyword=“'+tempHolder+'” />'+tempHolder+'</label></li>');
```

Wrap tempHolder with quotes as shown above.. html is doing it and it is considering first word.

sorry for bad formatting 
~answering from mobile.